# How to distribute requests over Unicorn and Puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, unicorn, puma

I have a Rails app currently running on Unicorn. I want to shift to Puma in such a way that the heavy requests are directed to the Puma server and the rest run like before on Unicorn. I'm using nginx.

I think I'll have to modify the nginx conf file somehow to divide such requests.

Is it possible?
Any link with info on this would be helpful so I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to distribute your requests among different 
locations in nginx:

```
location /something/light {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}
location /everything/else {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
}
```

Comment: this I figured out but the problem is that I'm in development mode and I want to start both unicorn and puma servers. So when a request to puma is made I can know through logs.

Comment: You mean to run puma and unicorn simultaneously on the same server?

Comment: yes, so that heavy requests are forwarded to puma and rest on unicorn. That's what I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Just put their servers on different ports and configure upstreams accordingly.